# Custom view is blank after setting android : targetSdkVersion="14" or above

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-custom-view

I have a custom `View` which is showing an animation using `android.graphics.Movie` class which decodes animation from the `InputStream`.

```
Movie.decodeStream(inputStream);
```

When I use this in my android manifest, animation on the view is showing correctly

```
 <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8" />
```

or

```
    <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="13" />
```

When I use this in my android manifest, there is blank view.

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="17"  />
```

Its also working well for android:targetSdkVersion="13" or below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My best guess is, that hardware acceleration is breaking your view.

To be sure it's the hardware acceleration, add this to your manifest:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
<application android:hardwareAccelerated="false" ...>
```

If it is working, try to switch off hardware acceleration for your view with

```
myView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```

See full documentation here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html

Comment: It's working but after using this I've to invalidate my view own my own.